# PyCharm displaying old versions of plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, robotframework, intellij-plugin

I am attempting to install https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7415-robot-framework-support in pycharm. The last update for this was on Jan 03, 2018.

When I try to find it in pycharm (settings -> plugins -> browse repositories...) it gives me a version last updated on 15 December 2015.

My proxy settings are working to the best of my knowledge (HTTP proxy -> check connection connects fine to the URL above).

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it work:

1. First delete old versions of Robot Framework plugins (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.1\plugins)'
2. Download new plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7415-robot-framework-support and extract it.
3. Change from plugins.xml (robot-plugin\META-INF\plugins.xml) line 4 to [image] and idea version: [image]
4. Zip that package again and install it via PyCharm "Install plugin from disk". [image]
5. Reboot PyCharm
6. Check plugins and should look like this:
   [image]

But I had same settings as you and I could not find the newest version from repositories.